# return array from tedious

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can't return an array. At the exit you need to get each value separately to insert into the database. Maybe somewhere I made a mistake with the callback. Code below.

```
function executeTest(connection, callback) {

    var results = [];

    var request = new Request(ted_select, function(error) {

        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }
        // pass the results array on through the callback
        callback(null, results);
    });

    request.on("row", function(rowObject) {
        // populate the results array
        results.push(rowObject);
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
}

function test(callback) {
    var connection = new Connection(config);
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Connect database');
            executeTest(connection, function(error, results) {
                // here is the results array from the first query
                console.log(results);
            });
            setTimeout(function(){connection.close(console.log('Disconnect database'));},10000);
        }
        callback(null, results);
    });
}

var value = test();
console.log(value);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Having some code up there is a good first step but you might want to walk us through some of it. Where is the head of the codepath and where is the "return" that you are talking about?

Comment: Head of the codepath I missed it, not to post all the code. Return changed on the "callback", before it was "return" end function "executeTest" and "Test"

Comment: You are calling `test()` without a callback function. `Undefined(..)` will kill the code because object `undefined` is not a function.

Comment: Please tell me how fix it.